# Refactor rename in C

Tags: c, plugins, visual-studio-2013, ide

I'm developing in c, using visual studio 2013.
I wonder if there is a way in visual studio, or a plugin, that enable to refactor names of variable/functions ...

If not, Is there any other recommended IDE that enables refactoring with C?
Thanks.

Comment: At least Eclipse CDT can do that. Not sure about VS.

Comment: Its weird that it is so complicated to understand if/how is it possible to do it in visual studio. its such a basic operation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/default.asp) (commercial) and [Visual C++ Refactoring](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/164904b2-3b47-417f-9b6b-fdd35757d194) (free) extensions for VS 2013 support the rename refactoring for C.

Comment: Great thanks! I downloaded the Visual C++ Refactoring, and its working just fine.